# Flutter: popAndPushNamed with arguments passing to new page?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am writing an application on Flutter. I need to do popAndPushNamed but I also need to pass arguments to the Page I am pushing. How can I do? Is there another way to pop and push or I have to look for a different solution? This thing is making me insane.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

For sending data to widget you can use it's constructor

```
String result = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondWidget("String")));
```

In this case `result` is new string, which will be returned from `SecondWidget`

```
class SecondWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondWidget(this.text);
  final String text;
```

And somewhere in `SecondWidgetState`:

```
Navigator.pop(context, "New string");
```

This will close `SecondWidget` and return value for `result`
I think it's clear enough and it'll help

**UPD**
How to do in your case (something like this)

```
Profile profile = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginWidget()));
if (profile != null) Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainWidget(profile)));
```

In `LoginWidget`:

```
void _afterLogIn() {
  // do something
  Navigator.pop(context, this.receivedProfile);
}
```

In `MainWidget`:

```
class MainWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MainWidget(this.profile);
  Profile profile;
```

Comment: I do not understand. You mean to do just push and, only after I finished with the second widget, do pop? I need to pop the first widget and push the second. I am implementing an app with login, after the user has signed in I need to dispose the login page and push the main widget.

Comment: Question is specifically about popAndPushNamed